# How to paginate search results?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I want to paginate search results using [**Zend_Paginator**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.paginator.html). So I pass my data to a paginator instance:

```
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator ( 
           new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect ( $data ) 
);
```

Data is returned this way

```
public function getData($idArray){
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $selectProgramme = new Zend_Db_Select($db);

        $selectProgramme->from('programme')
                            ->order('id DESC')
                            ->where('id IN(?)', $idArray);

        return $selectProgramme;        
}
```

`$idArray` is provided by my search implementations. This all works great and I get the correct data and pagination links displayed.

However I can't paginate the result because the pagination links are not valid. So normal pagination would have following link:

```
mysite.de/home/index/page/1
```

in search I now have

```
mysite.de/home/search/page/1
```

This does not work. Any suggestions how to implement search pagination?

**EDIT:** I have a `HomeController` with two actions, index and search action. IndexAction displays all data and I can paginate it.

```
public function indexAction(){
    //...
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(
                 new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($data)
    );
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(16)
              ->setPageRange(20)
              ->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page', 1));

    $this->view->data = $paginator;
}
```

The searchActions handles the search process:

```
public function searchAction(){
    $response = $solr->search($this->getRequest()->getParam('search', null));
    //...if items found get the data exactly the same way as in the 
    // index action, using Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(
                 new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($data)
    );
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(16)
              ->setPageRange(20)
              ->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page', 1));

    $this->view->data = $paginator;
}
```

So like you see in the search action there is a problem with the search process when I paginate. I need to decide somehow if to search or to paginate. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Post whole action code, because I can't understand what result of the routing process do you get. Are you using searchAction or indexAction for pagination?

Comment: I updated my question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since search required the search parameter pagination will fail because when paginating the the search parameter is null.

```
$sreq = $this->getRequest()->getParam('search', null);
```

So we need to pass this parameter whenever we paginate our search. I solve this using `Zend_Session`:

```
//get search param
$sreq = $this->getRequest()->getParam('search', null);
//store search param in session for pagination
$search = new Zend_Session_Namespace('PSearch');

if($sreq != null){
    $search->psearch = $sreq;
}else{
   $sreq = $search->psearch;
}
```

I have this at the top of my searchAction and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand, but is your problem that the page parameter from the url is not making it's way to the Paginator - e.g. regardless of what page you are on, it is always showing the first 20 results?

If so, have you tried manually setting the page on the paginator:

```
$page = $this->_getParam('page', 1);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

Comment: Have a look at my update. When I change page to two I get page two as expected, navigation using the pagination links does not work because I need to modify the searchAction somehow

Comment: I can not paginate search results, thats it. Imagine I make a search. then the route looks like mysite.net/home/search. but when I try to paginate it tries to access mysite.net/home/search/page/2 and that fails because he runs the search again but he shouldn't...

Answer (score 1):

```
public function search()
```

Are you sure that you didn't mistyped here? Should be

```
public function searchAction()
```

Comment: What $solr->search(null) will return? Could this cause no items for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

You put your search data into `$response` but create paginator instance using `$data` (which is null)